# Proving a set is open

Tags: real-analysis

> Show that the set of $\mathbb{R}^2$ given by $E = \{(x, y) \in
>  \mathbb{R}^2 : x > y\}$ is open.

I know I must determine a radius $r$ such that $$\{(x_1, y_2)\in \mathbb{R}^2: \sqrt{|x-y|^2 +|x_1-y_1|^2}<r\}$$

but how can I find such an $r$?

Comment: What does the set $E$ look like? You should be able to find the solution with some geometric reasoning.

Comment: @EricStucky it says it is a half plane that has boundaries $y=-x$ but I don't know how they got that?

Comment: No explanation on the topology side is going to be helpful until you can visualize this set. Notice it is defined in terms of an inequality; do you know a technique to graph inequalities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Locate the region of the plane where $x\gt y$.  Put a point $P=(x_1,y_1)$ in it, say with $P$ fairly close to the line $y=x$.

Now move to the left from $P$ until you hit the line $y=x$, say at $Q$. Then $Q$ has coordinates $(y_1,y_1)$.

Let $x_1=y_1+\delta$, where $\delta$ is positive. Argue that the distance from $P$ to the line is $\frac{\delta}{\sqrt{2}}$. So if we take a disk with centre $P$ and $\dots$.

Comment: $Q$ has coordinates $(y_1, y_1)$ since $y=x$? So it can also have coordinates $(x_1,x_1)$ too?

Comment: The region of the plane where $x>y$ is the first quadrant also the forth quadrant ?

Comment: If we had gone up instead of to the left, we would have hit $R=(x_1,x_1)$. That would have given you the geometry too. I was trying to give a brief geometrical indication of why distance to the line is $\delta/\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: The region is the region "below" $y=x$. So it is all of the fourth quadrant, half of the first, half of the third.

Comment: Got ya on the region parts. But what do you mean by "If we had gone up instead of to the left"?

Comment: We start from a point $P=(x_1,y_1)$ in the set. If we go straight up from $P$, we get to a point $R$ on $y=x$ with unchanged $x$-coordinate $x_1$, but with $y$-coordinate equal to $x_1$. The distance $PR$ is $\delta$, just like $QP$ is $\delta$.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that but I tried to show that the radius is $\frac{\delta}{\sqrt2}$ but I cant figure how you got that?

Comment: Geometry. Draw the line through $P$ perpendicular to $y=x$, meeting the line $y=x$ at $S$. Then $QSP$ is an isosceles right-angled triangle with hypotenuse $\delta$.

Comment: Im sorry Andre, but I still don't understand how you got that. I've been trying to work it out the past 20 mins. I drew the plot of a line $y=x$ and placed my point $P$ on the x-axis and my point $Q$ in the origin but I still cant figure out how you got $\frac{x_1-y_1}{\sqrt2}$?

Comment: OK, let's go to your picture. Take the point $P=(a,0)$. Draw the perpendicular from $P$ to the line $y=x$. Suppose this perpendicular meets the line $y=x$ at $S$. Then $\triangle OSP$ is right-angled and isosceles. Let $d$ be the distance $PS$. Then $d=OS$. By the Pythagorean Theorem, $d^2=d^2=a^2$, so $d=\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: I have a few questions. So $OS$ is the hypotenuse and the variable $O$ is some point on the line $y=x$ right above $P$ forming the right angle? And how come $d=OS$ **and** $d=PS$?

Comment: The hypotenuse is $OP$.

Comment: No wonder! I placed my perpendicular line parallel to the point P. Ah! Stupid mistake. Thank you very much!!

Comment: You are welcome. Our exchanges illustrate the importance of pictures. It would have taken seconds to explain things on a blackboard.

Answer (score 3):

One alternate definition I like about open and closed sets is based on their borders. Define the border of a set $S$ as "the set of all points $B$ s.t. if $x \in B$, for every neighborhood $U$ around x, at least point in U is a point in $B$ and one point is in the compliment $B^c$".

From this it's pretty easy to get working definitions of open and closed sets: Clearly every point in $B$ is a limit point of $S$, and every limit point of $S$ will either be in S or be in $B$ (if it's not, then there are neighborhoods without any points in $S$, so it can't be a limit point). So a closed set is one which contains its border. Similarly, given a point x, if we can find an open ball $R$ around x st $R \subset S$, x can't be on the border. So an open set is one which does not contain any points in its border.

Pulling back to your problem. What's the border of $E$? It shouldn't be hard to argue that it's $B_E = \{(x,y): x=y \}$. Now, is $B_e \cap E = \emptyset$? If $x>y$, then $x\neq y$ and $B_e \cap E = \emptyset$. Therefore E is open.

EDIT: You'll probably want to do it a more conventional way too, but hopefully this is enough to convince you that it's true.

Comment: I need some time to gather all this information in. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you know about continuous functions, then $E=f^{-1}(0,\infty)$ for $f:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ given by $f(x,y)=x-y$. It follows that $E$ is open because $f$ is continuous and $(0,\infty)$ is open in $\mathbb R$.