# How to prove that an open ball is contained in some set?

Tags: analysis

Before asking my question, I'd ask you to read the following question :

[Proving a set is open](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/502977/proving-a-set-is-open)

I fully understand the geometric argument, and I can intuitively grasp that if were to choose an open ball centered at an arbitrary point in the set with a radius smaller than  $\frac{ \delta}{2} $ then the open ball would be a part of that set.

But how do I show this explicitly? If the set is defined by $E = \{(x, y) \in
 \mathbb{R}^2 : x > y\}$ , how do we should that for $B = \{y \in \mathbb{R}^2 : y - x < r \} ,  \forall r <  \frac{\delta}{2}, \Rightarrow B \subset E $?

My attempts have all been to show that from having y - x < $ \frac{\delta}{2} $, that it should follow that the set has the same property as E, but these attemps all lead to extremely messy algebra that I can't seem to simplify? Is there some general technique I am missing, or is this set already a subset of E by consutrction?

Comment: In metric spaces, in particular $\mathbb{R}^k$, to go from a visually obvious fact to the formal version one uses the Triangle Inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to show that, given arbitrary $(x_0, y_0) \in E$, there exists a open disk $D$ such that $D$ is centered at $(x_0,y_0)$, $D$ was radius $r$, and $D\subset E$ (this is what is required to show that a set $X \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is an open set in the standard topology). To show that $D \subset E$, we need that for any point $(x_2,y_2) \in D$, the distance between $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ is less than $r$.

We wish to pick an $r$ to make it easy to show that $D \subset E$. Because $(x,y) \in E$ (and thereby $x > y$, we know that $\exists z > 0$ such that $x = y + z$. As a guess pick $r = \frac{z}{2}$. If you consider the open square $S$ with corners of the form $(x_0 \pm \frac{z}{2}, y_0 \pm \frac{z}{2})$, you see that every point $(x_3,y_3) \in S$ will satisfy the inequalies $x_3 > x_0 - \frac{z}{2}$ and $y_3 < y_0 - \frac{z}{2}$. Therefore we know that $x_3 - y_3 > (x_0 - y_0) + z$. Knowing $x_0 - y_0 = z$, it follows that $$x_3 - y_3 > z - z \Longrightarrow x_3 > y_3 \Longrightarrow (x_3,y_3) \in S$$

But $(x_3,y_3)$ was an arbitrary point in $S$, so we can conclude that $S \subset E$. Then, we let $D$ be the open disk inscribe within the open rectangle $D$ (this means that $D$ has radius $r = \frac{z}{2} < z$). Because $D$ inscribes $S$, we know $D \subset S$, and therefore we know that $D \subset E$ as well, and, furthermore every point in $D$ has distance less that $r$ from $(x_0,y_0)$. Therefore the $D$ we have found satisfies all the necessary criteria to conclude that $E$ is an open set.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to show that if the point $P=(x_0,y_0)\in E$, then you can find a disk centred on $P$ which is entirely contained in $E$.

There are two things you need to grasp. $P\in E$ means $x_0>y_0$. That means (and this is the critical point) that we can find $\delta>0$ such that $x_0>y_0+\delta$.

The second point is how to relate that $\delta$ to a suitable radius for the disk. What you want to know is the perpendicular distance from $P$ to the line $y=x$. Then you can safely take the radius as some fraction of that distance. If you draw a picture you will see that the horizontal distance from $P$ to the line is the difference $x_0-y_0$ which is at least $\delta$. So remembering some basic geometry (a $90^o,45^o,45^o$ triangle) you can conclude that the perpendicular distance is at least $\frac{\delta}{\sqrt2}$. So you can take the radius of the disk as the smaller number $\frac{\delta}{2}$.

Comment: Yes this much was clear to me geometrically and intuitively, but how do I morph this into a formal proof? As in show that B is a subset of E?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by a formal proof. The proof above is rigorous. You just need to delete the waffle!